# Sync old Blackberry Calendar dates to Outlook

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, calendar, blackberry, device-manager

For some reason all of my calendar prior to August has been wiped out (from both calendars).

I still have my Blackberry data but the file extension is .ipd, which obviously I cannot open.

How can I open this file or somehow sync my older calendar dates and keep my calendars from deleting older dates in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work but... create a new Outlook profile first. Then using the BB desktop app synch you calendar to Outlook with this profile open. Then have outlook export the calander to excel. Delete the event you don't want. Open Outlook with the normal profile and import from the excell file.

Or at least that's how I would start my search on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not having problems with events that won't delete, I'm trying to restore events that Outlook deleted from its calendar and from the Blackberry's. I have a back up .ipd file of my older Blackberry calendar. I want to restore it and keep Outlook from deleting dates in the future.

Comment: then maybe try exporting your current Outlook calendar, then do the above, then re-import the current overwriting the old stuff.